# calculate messages count objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
- (int)getMsgLen:(NSString *)msg{
    int unicode = 0;//is arabic or english (1=arabic 0=english)
    NSString *str = @"دجحخهعغفقثصضطكمنتالبيسشظزوةىلارؤءئإلإألأآلآ،؛؟ءآأؤإئابةتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهوىيـًٌٍَُِّْ";

    for (int i = 0; i<[str length]; i++) {
        NSString *strResult = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];

        for (int r = 0; r<[msg length] ;r++) {
            NSString *msgResult = [msg substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(r, 1)];
            if([strResult isEqualToString:msgResult] && strResult)
                unicode = 1;
        }
    }

    int msgLenght = 1;

    // arabic value

    float oneMsgLenth = 70;
    float twoMsgLenth = 67;

    //  english value
    if(unicode == 0){
        oneMsgLenth = 160;
        twoMsgLenth = 134;
    }

    int numChar = [msg length];
    if( numChar > oneMsgLenth){
        msgLenght = ceil(numChar / twoMsgLenth);
    }
    return msgLenght;
}
```

I have this code,this code check if there any arabic characters to change the calculate number of messages, this code works every time when you write to a UITextView and it's working successfully, but it's too slow because every click it's changing the value of the UILabel.

Any advice to help me to make it very fast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase the speed of the loops at least, by exiting as soon as `unicode != 0`, and you could also do the comparison using the `NSCharacterSet` class which is initialised just once.

Add an instance variable in MyClass.h:

```
@interace MyClass : NSObject
{
    NSCharacterSet *_arabicChars;
}

...

@end
```

MyClass.m:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        _arabicChars = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"دجحخهعغفقثصضطكمنتالبيسشظزوةىلارؤءئإلإألأآلآ،؛؟ءآأؤإئابةتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهوىيـًٌٍَُِّْ"];
        ...
    }
    return self;
}

- (int)getMsgLen:(NSString *)msg{

    BOOL isArabic = [msg rangeOfCharacterFromSet:_arabicChars].location != NSNotFound;

    int msgLenght = 1;

    // arabic value

    float oneMsgLenth = 70;
    float twoMsgLenth = 67;

    //  english value
    if (!isArabic){
        oneMsgLenth = 160;
        twoMsgLenth = 134;
    }

    int numChar = [msg length];
    if( numChar > oneMsgLenth){
        msgLenght = ceil(numChar / twoMsgLenth);
    }
    return msgLenght;
}
```